# Windows Phone - Run HTML page in background

Tags: html, windows-phone-8, background-process

I have a HTML page which displays a counter for the number of seconds the page was open.

I want to display this page in Windows Phone, contained within its app.

Here, "open" would mean the following states:

1. The page is active.
2. The user has opened some other app, so the page is running in the background.
3. The user has locked the screen.

How can this functionality be achieved? Is it possible with the WebBrowser control? What are the other options - WPF / C# and XAML?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can use C#/XAML, C++/XNA or JS/CSS for developing Windows Phone app (WPF has nothing with this, it is desktop technologies for Windows OS).

You can display your page with `WebBrowser` control. But Windows Phone suspends your app process when user switches to other app, receive a call or lock a screen. If your counter is implemented on client side (on JS of your page) counter is suspended too.

What can you do - you can implement your counter on a server and when app will be resumed - call your server for updating your counter.

You can read about [App activation and deactivation for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for deeply understanding. Don't forgot to check [IsApplicationInstancePreserved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.activatedeventargs.isapplicationinstancepreserved%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property in Activation event for determine that app is resuming.

Comment: The "counter" is just an example.

What I am actually looking at is executing some JavaScript code of the page even in conditions when the app is suspended or the screen is locked.

Is there any such option? Can it be done in XAML / C# ("server-side").

Thanks.

Comment: Nope, you can't do it when app is suspended. I am mentioned that you can setup a server in the Internet, and when you start your app you can set some value on the server and when you resume your app - read this value in activate event. Not sure that it helps you but you can check Background agents for Windows Phone - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: If, from the "Xaml.cs" file, we call "Browser.InvokeScript" method (when the app is in background), is it possible that the corresponding Html file would be updated?